# FilesystemMetadataProvider: get metadata file

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

In our multi-tenant environment, we cannot configure our `MetadataProvider`'s in the spring file and have to create/retrieve/etc them at runtime. I am basically trying to persist `MetadataProvider`'s so that I can load them back on application restart. For `HttpMetadataProvider`, I can get the URL from `getMetadataURI()` method. However, I don't see a way of getting the location from a `FilesystemMetadataProvider`. Is there a way, else, I'll have to resort to reflections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `FilesystemMetadataProvider` class and override method `getMetadataIdentifier` with the following signature, in order to make it public:

```
 public String getMetadataIdentifier() {
     return super.getMetadataIdentifier();
 }
```

The method is returning absolute path to the metadata file. Then when defining your metadata, instead of using the original class you can use the new one and fetch the file name as you want.

Comment: Thanks @vladimir. Though your solution is easier to implement than reflections, it suffers from the same problem: the code becomes brittle as it's not a public accessor. Is there any reason why `FilesystemMetadataProvider.getMetadataIdentifier()` is not public while `HttpMetadataProvider.getMetadataURI()` is? Thanks again for your reply and developing and maintaining the extension.

Comment: Those classes come from OpenSAML which is not maintained by me, so I can't tell what were the original reasons to make these choices.